# What should be the correct XML xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

Here's the XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mtc="OTC_Matching_11-0" xmlns:rm="OTC_RM_11-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="OTC_RM_11-0 /xmls/OTC/OTC_RM_11-0.xsd  OTC_Matching_11-0  /xmls/OTC/OTC_Matching_11-0.xsd                           http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ /xmls/OTC/soap-envelope.xsd  ">
<env:Header>
  <OTC_RM xmlns="OTC_RM_11-0">
     <Manifest>
        <TradeMsg>
           <Activity>New</Activity>
           <Status>Submit</Status>
        </TradeMsg>
     </Manifest>
  </OTC_RM>
</env:Header>
</env:Envelope>
```

Shouldn't the xpath for **Activity** be:

```
/env:Envelope/env:Header/rm:OTC_RM/rm:Manifest/rm:TradeMsg/rm:Activity
```

I doesn't work. I am tried it [here](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester)

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose the `local-name()` function to address the default namespace. Try this:

```
/env:Envelope/env:Header/*[local-name()='OTC_RM']/*[local-name()='Manifest']/*[local-name()='TradeMsg']/*[local-name()='Activity']
```

Comment: Please add to your answer that using `local-name()` should only be your last resort and that most XPath libraries include means to declare prefixes and namespace URIs.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks. But can we access that element without using local-name() function?  Do we have any other way?

Comment: It depends on what you are using. Please see this link (http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html).

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't work as the namespace gets defaulted at OTC_RM.
Hence, you would have to declare this namespace and a prefix for it(example `xmlns:rm="OTC_RM_11-0"`) OTC_RM and it's children. And you would be able to access the `Activity` element from the following xpath:

```
/env:Envelope/env:Header/rm:OTC_RM/rm:Manifest/rm:TradeMsg/rm:Activity
```

[Try it here](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQN).

**EDIT**
The XML shall be updated, to work on the website you are using, to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mtc="OTC_Matching_11-0" xmlns:rm="OTC_RM_11-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="OTC_RM_11-0 /xmls/OTC/OTC_RM_11-0.xsd  OTC_Matching_11-0  /xmls/OTC/OTC_Matching_11-0.xsd                           http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ /xmls/OTC/soap-envelope.xsd  ">
<env:Header>
    <rm:OTC_RM>
        <rm:Manifest>
            <rm:TradeMsg>
                <rm:Activity>New</rm:Activity>
                <rm:Status>Submit</rm:Status>
            </rm:TradeMsg>
        </rm:Manifest>
    </rm:OTC_RM>
</env:Header>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: This answer is correct, +1. Perhaps you could add that the online tester used by the OP: http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester obviously automatically redeclares prefixes and namespaces, but cannot deal with default namespaces.

Comment: @Lingamurthy CS: I just updated the XML document. I had skipped few namespaces earlier. Still the xpath doesn't work. Can you point out the mistake I am making?

Comment: @DixitGokhale You shall update the XML as I've shown in my edited answer.. look at the added prefix(`rm`). Have updated the Xpath accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasMüller.. It worked on the online tester, but the save&share didn't work.. :(

Comment: @LingamurthyCS: Sadly I am not allowed to change XML in production. XML document I mentioned is how it is gonna come. I need to write appropriate xpath.  Is it possible?

Comment: @DixitGokhale in this case you can use JoelM.Lamsen's answer.. but it would select `Activity` elements irrespective of their namespaces.